# passing data in react from a child component up through the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures, react-hooks

I am a beginner and i have a structure like this:

```
<CountContext.Provider value={{ contextCount, setContextCount }}>
        <Wrapper />
        <Bar />
 </CountContext.Provider>
```

Inside the wrapper I have 12 cards, each with a click counter.
The bar contains a counter of all clicks, implemented through the context, as well as a reset button.
How can I, without using third-party libraries, reset not only the general counter, but also reset each individual counter on the cards?

More details:

```
export const CountContext = createContext();
const App = () => {
  const [contextCount, setContextCount] = useState(0);
 
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <CountContext.Provider value={{ contextCount, setContextCount }}>
        <Wrapper />
        <Bar />
      </CountContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
const Wrapper = () => {

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <Card color={card.color} key={card.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Wrapper;
```

```
const Card = ({ color }) => {
  const { contextCount, setContextCount } = useContext(CountContext);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const clickOnCard = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setContextCount((prev) => prev + 1);
  };
 
  return (
    <div
      className="card"
      style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
      onClick={clickOnCard}
    >
      {count}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

```
const Bar = () => {
  const { contextCount, setContextCount, styleBtn, setStyleBtn } =
    useContext(CountContext);
  const reset = () => {
    setContextCount(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="bar">
      Total Count:{contextCount}
      <button className="btn" onClick={reset}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I try useEffect, context, if-else, conditional render and some other ways.

Comment: We can't help more specifically without seeing the card code and overall component around the snippet you posted. But what you would do is, instead of storing one total number in the context, you would store a map of all the counts for each card in the context (against a unique id for each card). The card component would then have an ID prop so it knows which count to pull out of the context. And the total count could be provided through context as well by just adding up the numbers in the map. Since the counts for all cards are now in the context, you can reach into that to clear it down.

Comment: To clarify -- there would be no more local count state in the cards with this solution. This is a classic "hoist state" problem.

Comment: @adsy add component's code

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic "state hoisting" problem. The state of the counters for each card is currently kept in the `Card` component itself, so they are not within the scope of the context to be able to reset.

**Option A - State Hoisting**

The answer in these situations is usually to move that state upwards to bring it into scope.

To do this, we can store each number for each card inside the context provider in the form of a map where the key is the card ID and the value is the current count for that card. We will then pass accessors down so the cards can use the count and also provide a method to reset them.

```
export const CountContext = createContext();
const App = () => {
  const [counts, setCounts] = useState({});

  const getCount = useCallback((id) => counts[id] ?? 0, [counts]);

  const incrementCount = useCallback(
    (id) => {
      setCounts((prevCounts) => ({
        ...prevCounts,
        [id]: (prevCounts[id] ?? 0) + 1,
      }));
    },
    [counts],
  );

  const resetAllCounters = useCallback(() => {
    setCounts({});
  }, []);

  const totalCount = useMemo(
    () =>
      Object.values(counts).reduce(
        (accumulator, cardCount) => accumulator + cardCount,
        0,
      ),
    [counts],
  );

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <CountContext.Provider value={{ incrementCount, totalCount, resetAllCounters, getCount }}>
        <Wrapper />
        <Bar />
      </CountContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`Wrapper` is almost the same apart from we pass down the ID as a normal prop so the card can use it to identify the right count.

```
const Wrapper = () => {

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <Card color={card.color} id={card.id} key={card.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Wrapper;
```

`Card` now relies on the context for its current value and to update it.

```
const Card = ({ color, id }) => {
  const { incrementCount, getCount } = useContext(CountContext);

  const clickOnCard = () => {
    incrementCount(id);
  };
 
  return (
    <div
      className="card"
      style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
      onClick={clickOnCard}
    >
      {getCount(id)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

`Bar` just needs rewiring a little for the new naming:

```
const Bar = () => {
  const { totalCount, resetAllCounters } = useContext(CountContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Total Count: {totalCount}</p>
      <button onClick={resetAllCounters}>Reset All Counters</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you need to deal with the total count reducing if one of the `Card` unmounts you could achieve it using effects.

**Option B - Forced Reset**

This is far simpler, but **must be used with caution** and not become the default way of doing this without considering the trade-offs each time.

In this solution, you utilise React's `key` property. When this changes on a given component, it causes that component and all of its children to completely unmount and remount, which has the effect of clearing their state also.

The reason for being cautious is this means you are totally giving up on React performant diffing algorithm and just building up the DOM all over again when they hit reset. For trivial apps though, you might not care.

Also, it will wipe out any other transient state you have in the children. It's a "sledgehammer" approach. But it can be useful sometimes if you don't care about the above impacts and it has a bonus in that you don't have to manage the resets yourself.

In `App`:

```
export const CountContext = createContext();
const App = () => {
  const [contextCount, setContextCount] = useState(0);
  const [resetKey, setResetKey] = useState(0)

  const resetIndividualCounters = useCallback(() => {
     // Each time reset is called, change the key to force the tree to be recreated.
     setResetKey(prev => prev + 1)
  }, [])
 
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <CountContext.Provider value={{ contextCount, setContextCount, resetIndividualCounters }}>
        <Wrapper key={resetKey} />
        <Bar />
      </CountContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In `Bar`

```
const Bar = () => {
  const { resetIndividualCounters, contextCount, setContextCount, styleBtn, setStyleBtn } =
    useContext(CountContext);
  const reset = () => {
    setContextCount(0);
    resetIndividualCounters()
  };

  return (
    <div className="bar">
      Total Count:{contextCount}
      <button className="btn" onClick={reset}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: In regards to my last statement in option a, let me know if you think that's a requirement..

Comment: i will try it, thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

To achieve this without using third-party libraries, you can follow these steps:

1. **Modify Context:**
   Update your `CountContext` to include a function for resetting individual card counters. This function can be passed down to each card.

   ```
   const CountContext = createContext();

   const CountProvider = ({ children }) => {
     const [contextCount, setContextCount] = useState(0);

     const resetAllCounters = () => {
       setContextCount(0);
     };

     return (
       <CountContext.Provider value={{ contextCount, setContextCount, resetAllCounters }}>
         {children}
       </CountContext.Provider>
     );
   };
   ```
2. **Update Cards:**
   Pass the reset function down to each card and use it to reset the individual counters.

   ```
   const Card = ({ resetCardCounter }) => {
     const [cardCount, setCardCount] = useState(0);

     const handleCardClick = () => {
       setCardCount(cardCount + 1);
       resetCardCounter(); // Reset individual card counter
     };

     return (
       <div>
         <p>Card Counter: {cardCount}</p>
         <button onClick={handleCardClick}>Click me</button>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```
3. **Update Wrapper:**
   In the `Wrapper` component, render multiple instances of the `Card` component and pass the reset function to each card.

   ```
   const Wrapper = () => {
     const { resetAllCounters } = useContext(CountContext);

     const resetCardCounter = () => {
       // Logic to reset individual card counter
     };

     return (
       <div>
         {Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, index) => (
           <Card key={index} resetCardCounter={resetCardCounter} />
         ))}
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```
4. **Update Bar:**
   In the `Bar` component, use the context to access the `resetAllCounters` function and implement the reset button.

   ```
   const Bar = () => {
     const { contextCount, resetAllCounters } = useContext(CountContext);

     return (
       <div>
         <p>Total Count: {contextCount}</p>
         <button onClick={resetAllCounters}>Reset All Counters</button>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

Now, when you click the "Reset All Counters" button in the `Bar` component, it will reset both the general counter and the individual counters on each card. Adjust the logic inside the `resetCardCounter` function in the `Wrapper` component based on your requirements for resetting individual card counters.

Comment: This is incorrect and basically entirely misses the point.  Please be reminded of stack overflows position on answers generated using GPT. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned